# Rails Application using Nginx working on HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have been trying to get my application working in production.  I was able to access the site before changing `config.force_ssl = true` in my `config\environments\production.rb`.

I have seen many others with this problem need to add `proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-Proto https;`

I have tried adding this in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` but haven't seen a difference.

My full `default` is below:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80; 
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl; 

  root /var/www/html; 

  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html

  server_name appname.com www.appname.com

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

}
```

After making changes I reloaded nginx using `sudo service nginx reload` followed by `sudo service nginx stop` and `sudo service nginx start`

Am I missing something?

---

*EDIT*:

I updated my `default` and removed the `config.force_ssl = true`:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/kiui/apps/appnamw/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  keepalive_timeout   70;
  server_name appname.com www.appname.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /root/appname.com.chain.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /root/appname.com.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  root /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

I can now access the site with http but not https.

Comment: Are we correct to assume that you replaced `appname.com` with your actual domain?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I figured it out, will update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was where I was adding the code above.  I was adding it in `default`  rather than `nginx.conf`.  Moving the code above solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name appname.com www.appname.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  # SSL configuration
  ssl on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate path-to-your-crt-file;
  ssl_certificate_key path-to-your-key-file;
  server_name appname.com www.appname.com;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @saratibbetts, what is the response when you type `https://www.appname.com` into your address bar? And could you check your Nginx logs, both access log and error log.